# SQL Query To Select Zodiac Sign

Tags: sql

Plese tell me sql query to select zodiac sign by birth date.

Here is the table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE constellation
    constellation_name VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    start_date INTEGER,
    end_date INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO constellation
    VALUES ('Aries', 321,419), ('Taurus',420 ,520),
           ('Gemini', 521,621), ('Cancer',622 ,722),
           ('Leo', 723,822), ('Virgo',823 ,922)
           ('Libra', 923,1023), ('Scorpio',1024 ,1122),
           ('Sagittarius',1123 ,1221), ('Capricorn', 1222,119),
           ('Aquarius', 120,218), ('Pisces', 219,320);
```

Comment: What do those integers have to do with dates?  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: they means month and day.

Comment: For Example march 21 is 321

Comment: Sorry but that is a horrible design. Why wouldn't you use native date type of your database? Or at least integer day of year?

Comment: just use date type for dates, would be more simple, why making it complex

Comment: Month and day are better stored in two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `varchar(5)` is not going to get you very far with most zodiac signs.

You can use a `join`.  Most databases have functions such as `month()` and `day()`, although they might be named a little differently.

The idea is:

```
select t.*, c.constellation_name
from t join
     constellation c
     on month(dob) * 100 + day(dob) between start_mmdd and end_mmdd
```

EDIT:

To handle Capricorn:

```
select t.*, c.constellation_name
from t join
     constellation c
     on (start_mmdd < end_mmdd and 
         month(dob) * 100 + day(dob) between start_mmdd and end_mmdd
        ) or
        (start_mmdd > end_mmdd and 
         (month(dob) * 100 + day(dob) >= start_mmdd or
          month(dob) * 100 + day(dob) <= end_mmdd
        ) ;
```

Comment: thank sir. I am using varchar(5) because zodiac name will be inserted with Japanese language.I am sorry but this query do not work for Capricorn sign.

Comment: Like if the birthday is 1995/01/11 , the result of the query is null.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I want. Thank you so much.